# Example finitely generated ideal by non-irreducible elements

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring (it doesn't need to be commutative nor unitary). I wonder if any finitely generated maximal ideal of $R$ must be generated by irreducible elements. I haven't been able to prove it (well, I don't know whether it's true), and of course, on the other hand, I haven't found a counterexample either.

Comment: What do you mean by irreducible in such a general ring?

Comment: I haven't studied non-commutative rings without unit, so I don't know if there's a notion of irreducible element there.

Comment: I didn't ask if the notion exists already, I asked what *you* mean by the notion, since it's *you* using it here.

Comment: Well, I understand an element $x$ (non-unit and non-zero) is called irreducible if any decomposition of it as a product $y\times z$ implies either $y$ or $z$ is a unit. I don't know if I get your question, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R=2Z$ and let $I=(4)$. In this case $I$ is maximal and is generated by an element not irreducible.

Comment: Thanks. So here it comes Chris's point above: Why is $4$ not a irreducible element? I haven't found a definition of irreducible element in a ring without a unit.

Comment: It is irreducible by the definition you suggested.

Comment: @Hurkyl yeah, you're right. I really appreciate your participation here.

Comment: @user012 The concept is generally given for integral domains (equipped with units, ie of at least one element invertible), but according to your question, it seems to me that these hypotheses could be relaxed. And there is no reason not to define "irreducible element" in a generic ring without unity ... trivially, every element will be not invertible (a unit) so evry (eventually) decomposition for an element $a$ will give $a$ is reducible. So you want to know if this is possible  in a integral domain?

Comment: @Hurkyl It seemed clear from the user012 question
*it doesn't need to be commutative nor unitary*
it is not necessarily requested the existence of the unit. Then, extending the definition of "irreducible", it happens in 2Z each element is (trivially) reducible. At this point, we must see if we can generate a maximal ideal from a minimum set of all reducible generators, using the standard concept of irreducibility. Well...

Answer (score 1):

We can carry out the proof in the following way.
The first thing to do is further refine the hypothesis, that is we  must not set the problem for a general integral domain, but we must take instead a *unique factorization domain* (the $R$ eligible therefore reduces to that class of integral domains). Let $(a_1,..., a_n) = I$ with $a_i$ reducible for some $i$ and with $n$ the smallest $n$ for which this occurs. For the uniqueness of the factorization we have $a_i = p_1^i ... p_{m(i)}^i$ for all $i$ with the $p_k^i$'s irreducible. So considering the ideal $(p_{1}^1,..., p_1^n) = I'$ it follows that $I \subset I'$ and so the ideal is necessarily generated by irreducible elements that together form a generator of $I'$ with cardinality less or equal to that of the starting generator.
(If anyone sees a mistake in what I wrote, please highlight it.)